# How can I limit an associated entity result in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have the following query:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
                      SELECT u, p, m
                      FROM MyCoreBundle:User u
                      JOIN u.programmes p
                      JOIN u.motivation m
                      ');

$result = $query->getResult();
```

I want to restrict the motivation objects returned for each user to be the result of this second query which I am using elsewhere (On the Motivation repository):

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
                      SELECT m FROM MyCoreBundle:Motivation m
                      WHERE m.user = :user
                      ORDER BY m.date DESC');

$query->setParameter('user',$user);
$query->setFirstResult(0);
$query->setMaxResults(1);
//@TODO if there is not result recorded for the user, return sth which indicates this
return $query->getResult();
```

Is there a way to limit and restrict motivation in the first query or a better approach?

Comment: Considering written below, and assuming that "latest motiviation" is of primary importance for you and it will be accessed a lot, possible solution is to create `User:LatestMotivation` OneToOne relatinship. And then every time a new `Motivation` entity is added, (via Doctrine `prePersist` events) update the `LatestMotivation` with the newly added one. This way you will be able to iterate over many `User` records fetching the latest motivation. HTH

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't limit the number of joint rows.

If you have Doctrine 2.1 you can use `->slice()` on the collection:

```
$collection = $user->getMotivations();    // returns a LazyCollection, 
                                          // makes no SQL query

$motivations = $collection->slice(0, 20); // queries the first 20 motivations 
                                          // for this user (if the association
                                          // was not fetch-joint)
```

See http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Comment: Thanks - I got round it by adding another method to my User Entity which just adds a single motivation entry, looping over the object and overwriting the $motivation property. Dirty but it works.

Comment: @amaud576875 Unfotunately the slice method initializes the associations only for the current user. If you loop over multiple users multiple queries are produced. Is there a way how to fetch sliced collection for all the users?

Comment: @PetrPeller I have similar problem. Did you managed to solve it?

Comment: @svlada Not yet. Wonder if there are changes in Doctrine 2.2 that could help. Did you find something?

Comment: @arnaud576875 `slice()` method _seems_ cool, but there're two pitfalls: 1) the association `User.motivations` should be declared as `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"`. If you leave it to default value of `"LAZY"` then ALL of the motivations will be queried from DB and then sliced, instead of only querying 20. 2) `queries the first 20 motivations` is a bit of vague... usually for solving your domain  task you may want *latest* 20 motivations e.g. `ORDER BY m.date DESC` but `slice()` doesnt provide chance to sort them. Thus despite I was very excited to find `slice()` it quickly unfit for solving real problem